# Django queryset: check for foreignkey values and substract them from queryset

Tags: python, django

Let's imagine we have 2 models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    status = models.Charfield(choices=choices.STATUS, default='pending')

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="entries")
    text = models.TextField()
    ready = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Every blog can has many entries. I want to filter all entries with **ready = True** whose blog has the **status = published**.

Comment: `can be added in many blogs`, `...whose blog...` - which blog out of many? Do all linked blogs have to be in this status?

Comment: According to your model `Entry` has only one `Blog`, but one `Blog` can have many `Entries`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(ready=True, blog__status='published')
```